Ubutu 22.04 freezes after connecting Android Phone to USB
I have two Ubuntu 22.04 machines and one of them is freezing every time I connect an Android device (MTP and Android debug option are enabled since I'm android developer).
The system freezes even if I don't log in on the Gnome.
If I'm already using gnome, the mouse can move but nothing else responds.
I managed to capture this syslog
kernel: [ 2538.580224] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
kernel: [ 2538.734004] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860, bcdDevice= 4.00
kernel: [ 2538.734015] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
kernel: [ 2538.734018] usb 3-1: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
kernel: [ 2538.734021] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
kernel: [ 2538.734024] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: ce011711dd32cd3305
colord[1450]: CdMain: failed to emit DeviceAdded: failed to register object: An object is already exported for the interface org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Device at /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/sysfs__null_
kernel: [ 2538.767538] cdc_acm 3-1:1.1: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
kernel: [ 2538.767568] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
kernel: [ 2538.767570] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
kernel: [ 2538.790587] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 5
gnome-shell[8149]: Unable to mount volume SAMSUNG Android: Gio.IOErrorEnum: Couldn’t find matching udev device.
snapd[1178]: hotplug.go:200: hotplug device add event ignored, enable experimental.hotplug
ModemManager[1270]: <info>  [base-manager] port ttyACM0 released by device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3'
ModemManager[1270]: <info>  [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3': Operation was cancelled

By comparing with the machine that is working fine, I managed to add the following file:
cat /lib/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

....

#   Samsung
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", ENV{adb_user}="yes"
....

Even after adding that file and rebooting the system, I get the same message:
gnome-shell[8149]: Unable to mount volume SAMSUNG Android: Gio.IOErrorEnum: Couldn’t find matching udev device.

If I reboot the system with the device attached, it does not freezes but it also does not recognize it... lsusb does not show the device.
This is the lsusb result for that device on the other machine that is working fine
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy A5 (MTP)

The notebooks I'm using are:

Dell Latitude 3420 (have the issue)
Dell Latitude 5440 (works fine)

